# How to make status bar inactive in custom dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-dialog, android-statusbar

Hey i want my status bar inactive please look in image it have shadow on it or something. This is my **BottomSheetDialogFragment**.

[image]

when i opening my **custom dialog** inside **BottomSheetDialogFragment** class it active the status bar color turns into white.

[image]

I have code for my Custom Dialog class

```
class CustomDialog(
    context: Context,
) : Dialog(context) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val screenWidth = (displayMetrics(context).widthPixels * 0.8).toInt()
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout)
        window?.setLayout(screenWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    }
}
```

Someone know how to make inactive status bar as first image shows?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the style of the bottomsheet.

```
<style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_dialog</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

and Finally add this style:

```
  <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Base.Theme.MyApp">
            <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: can we set this style to programmatically in customDialog class? @Muhammad

Comment: `class CustomDialog(
    context: Context,
) : Dialog(context,R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme) {` not working

Comment: You don't need to add the bottom sheet style programmatically just add in the base Theme then This will change all the BottomSheetDialogs of your app.

Comment: i tried in my base style also its not working

Comment: `<style name="ApplicationTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>                                          
       <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
    </style>`